# Multiprocessing in Python for image batch streaming and processing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Developed a multiprocessing code in Python.
Image batch streaming is done in one process and batch processing in another process.

Once batch streaming has pre-defined number of images, signal to batch processing loop using MultiProcess.Event(). So the two processes need to be in correct timing.

Batch streaming time is longer than batch processing time, so there is no image loss in processing part.

Most of the time batch processing time is shorter than batch streaming time. So my batch processing side looks working ok. But sometimes, found that batch streaming is repeated for two times and followed by batch processing for example,

```
batch streaming 2.35
batch processing 2.05
batch streaming 2.25
batch processing 2.05
batch streaming 2.32  repeated
batch streaming 2.36
batch processing 3.25
batch streaming 2.35
batch processing 2.15
batch streaming 2.35
batch processing 2.25
```

That means I have image loss in processing part.
How can I solve the problem?

I can't post the whole code.
So two processes are as follow.

Batching streaming loop

```
while (not stopbit.is_set()):
        if not cam_queue.empty():
            #print('Got frame')            
            cmd, val = cam_queue.get()

            # calculate FPS
            '''diffTime = time.time() - lastFTime
            fps = 1 / diffTime
            print(fps)
            lastFTime = time.time()'''

            # if cmd == vs.StreamCommands.RESOLUTION:
            #     pass #print(val)

            if cmd == vs.StreamCommands.FRAME:
                if val is not None:
                    missCount=0
                    image = np.array(val, dtype=np.float32, order='C')
                    image=image.transpose([2, 0, 1])
                    imgrshp=image.reshape(921600)
                    #print(str(val.shape))
                    if (batch1_is_processed == False):
                        batch1_[count] = imgrshp#it is 921,600 flat array
                        batch3_[count] = val
                    else:
                        batch2_[count] = imgrshp
                        batch4_[count] = val
                    count = count + 1
                    if (count >= BATCHSIZE):  # to start process for inference and post processing
                        diffTime = time.time() - lastFTime
                        print("batching time " + str(diffTime))
                        if (batch1_is_processed == False):  # process batch1
                            q.put('batch1')
                            batch1_is_processed = True
                            #print('batch1 is set')

                        else:  # process batch2
                            q.put('batch2')
                            batch1_is_processed = False
                            #print('batch2 is set')

                        e.set()#to signal the buffer is full
                        count = 0
                        lastFTime = time.time()
                else:
                    missCount = missCount + 1
                    print("miss frame after " + str(time.time() - startTime))
                    if(missCount >= 10):
                        q.put('lostframes')
                        e.set()#so that immediately will go back to caller to stop with lostframes option
```

Batch processing

```
while(self.stopbit is not None):
                self.e.wait()
                batch = self.queue.get()
                lastFTime = time.time()
                if(batch == 'batch1'):#process batch1
                    #print('batch1 is processed')
                    for idx in range(BATCHSIZE):
                        images[idx] = np.frombuffer(self.sharedbatch1[idx], dtype=np.float32)
                        uimg = np.frombuffer(self.sharedbatch3[idx], dtype=np.uint8)
                        uimgs[idx] = uimg.reshape(HEIGHT,WIDTH,CHANNEL)
                elif(batch == 'batch2'):#process batch1
                    #print('batch2 is processed')
                    for idx in range(BATCHSIZE):
                        images[idx]=np.frombuffer(self.sharedbatch2[idx], dtype=np.float32)
                        uimg = np.frombuffer(self.sharedbatch4[idx], dtype=np.uint8)
                        uimgs[idx] = uimg.reshape(HEIGHT,WIDTH,CHANNEL)
                elif(batch == 'lostframes'):
                    self.e.clear()
                    self.stopbit.set()#to stop streaming
                    break
                #do batch processing in Nvidia's TensorRT
                with engine.create_execution_context() as context:
                    inputs, outputs, bindings, stream = common.allocate_buffers(engine)
                    inputs[0].host = np.ascontiguousarray(images, dtype=np.float32)
                    [outputs] = common.do_inference(context, bindings, inputs, outputs, stream, BATCHSIZE)
                    outputs=outputs.reshape((BATCHSIZE, 60, 80, 57))
                    humans=[]
                    for i in range(BATCHSIZE):
                       heat_map=outputs[i, :, :, :19] 
                       puf_map=outputs[i, :, :, 19:]
                       humans.append(self.est.inference(heat_map, puf_map, 4.0))

                       #uimgs[i]=TfPoseEstimatorTRT.draw_humans(uimgs[i], humans[i], imgcopy=False)
                       #cv2.imwrite("images/image_"+str(cnt)+".jpeg", uimgs[i])
                       #cnt=cnt+1 
                    hdp.ProcessHumanData(humans, uimgs)
                    #for i in range(BATCHSIZE):
                    #   cv2.imwrite("images/image_"+str(cnt)+".jpeg", uimgs[i])
                    #   cnt=cnt+1
                       #cv2.imshow('display',uimgs[i])
                       #cv2.waitKey(1)
                    humans.clear()
                    diffTime = time.time() - lastFTime
                    print("batch processing time "+str(diffTime))
                    self.e.clear()
```

Comment: Could you provide simplified code ? I'm interested in the calls between your two process (stopbit and e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved using Lock from Multiprocessing. Sometime, debugging using print is misleading. Printing itself takes some msec. That needs to be aware in debugging Parallel Processing code.